# How to make UILabel from custom cell display saved changes in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, userdefaults

I am a beginner in Swift. I've exhausted all my trial and errors and need help!!

I am creating a scoreboard project using a UITableView with a Custom Cell that holds a UILabel and a UIButton. After a button press the UILabel increments by one to simulate a point for the player. I am having trouble saving the point in UILabel so that every time I open the app the point for that player remains. I've tried using UserDefaults, structs, and delegates but have't had any luck...I could be doing it wrong. I just need to know what the proper approach is for this.

Note: I am able to save the player name successfully from the UIAlertController so that when I open the app the names are still there unless I delete them, but haven't had any luck saving the points for each name itself, they still remain "0".

It should look like this when I close then open the app, but it only does this when the app is opened:

[Scoreboard UITableView - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMosk.png)

Here's the ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var items = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        alert()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        listTableView.dataSource = self
        self.items = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey:"items")  ?? [String]()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PointsCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func saveData() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
    }

    func alert(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Player", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField{
            (textfield) in
            textfield.placeholder = " Enter Player Name "

        }
        let add = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default)
            {

            (action) in guard let textfield = alert.textFields?.first else {return}

            if let newText = textfield.text
            {
                self.items.append(newText)
                self.saveData()
                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.items.count - 1, section: 0)
                self.listTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
            (alert) in

        }

        alert.addAction(add)
        alert.addAction(cancel)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        saveData()

    }

}
```

Here is my custom cell code called PointsCell:

```
import UIKit

class PointsCell: UITableViewCell {

    var winScore = 0
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreUILabel: UILabel!

   @IBAction func pointButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        winScore += 1
        scoreUILabel.text = "\(winScore)"

    }

}
```

Comment: Please share saveData() code too

Comment: Ok i found saveData(). Please reload data in viewDidload() after assigning the value to self.items it will fix your prob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cells are dequeued and storing data inside cell subclass won't work, choose different strategy. Your `items` array should hold this informations about *points*, so to achieve this, you'll need you custom model.

---

First of all, make array of your custom models. This model will hold title and and number of points of item

```
struct Item {
    var title: String
    var points: Int

    init(title: String, points: Int = 0) {
        self.title = title
        self.points = points
    }
}
```

then change type of your array to array of `Item`

```
var items = [Item]()
```

Now in `cellForRowAt` set outlets depending on item for index

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PointsCell
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    cell.scoreUILabel.text = "\(item.points)"
    return cell
}
```

But now, how to handle that user presses button in cell and how to increase score?

One solution is to create closure variable in `UITableViewCell` subclass and when button will be pressed this closure will let controller know that button's been pressed

```
class PointsCell: UITableViewCell {

    var buttonPressed: (()->Void)?

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreUILabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func pointButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        buttonPressed?()
    }

}
```

then inside `cellForRowAt` assign this parameter and say that if button is pressed, increase `points` of this item and reload this row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PointsCell
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    cell.scoreUILabel.text = "\(item.points)"

    cell.buttonPressed = { // this gets called when `buttonPressed?()` is called from cell class
        self.items[indexPath.row].points += 1
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        saveData() // optional
    }

    return cell
}
```

---

Note, that with this strategy you will also need to change appending new element to appending `Item` (btw, you can safely force-unwrap `text` of `UITextField` since this this property is never `nil`)

```
self.items.append(Item(title: textfield.text!))
self.saveData()
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.items.count - 1, section: 0)
self.listTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

---

Also note that for saving custom model to `UserDefaults` you'll need to encode and decode your custom model, so you'll need to implement `Codable` to your struct

```
struct Item: Codable {
    //...
}
```

and then for saving use `JSONEncoder`:

```
func saveData() {
    do {
        let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(items)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "items")
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

and for retrieving, `JSONDecoder`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    listTableView.dataSource = self

    do {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:"items") {
            items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
        }
    } catch { print(error) }
}
```

---

One last note for future: `UserDefaults` aren't designed for storing big amount of data and in future programming life you'll definitely use some database like `Realm` or native `CoreData`.

Good luck btw! ;)

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!